# In Visual Studio can I have using static import in quick refactorings menu

Tags: visual-studio, unity-game-engine

In Visual Studio when I right click on let's say function and choose "Quick Actions and Refactorings" option (or just do Ctrl+.), can I somehow have using static import option be populated if the function exists in the project as static function in another class?

So, the result of it would be using static added on top of the file, for instance:
`using static Core.Unity.Logging.LogExtensions`
which would allow me for just plain function call instead of need to specify class name to.

[Static method image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2EHk9.png)

[Use of the static method image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Y4Z7f.png)

[Missing option image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/DWkZJ.png)

I tried to explore some options in visual studio, but couldn't find much.

Comment: If you want to do this in multiple code files, you might consider adding a  "GlobalUsings.cs" file (filename is actually arbitrary) containing the using, e.g. `global using static Core.Unity.Logging.LogExtensions;` then it will be in scope for every code file without needing the `using` at the top of the file. This requires C# 10 - seems like you're using Unity; I don't know if that supports C#10.

Comment: I believe you'd have to find (or write) a VS extension to customize the `ctrl+.` menu as it's dynamic

Comment: Yeah.. I've seen some trying to run C#10 in Unity, I'll check it out.. though creating extension is nice option too - seen some tutorials on yt.